# What is __spText1 and __spText2 used for?

Tags: 2010, master-page, custom-masterpage

Hello I am new to SharePoint and I wanted to make a custom master page.

I've stumbled on `__spText1` and `__spText2` and I was wondering if I can remove them? If not, what do they do / represent?

Thank you.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this is about SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

The only references I've found to the actual use of these hidden fields is a vague reference to them being required to handle the back button functionality ([SP2010 Master Page modifications showing up on other pages like "Add New Item"](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/605e7c2d-a87a-4377-b714-2da4baf89803)), the fact that this data needs to be posted to the server if using javascript to submit the page's form ([Using jQuery to submit forms on remote SharePoint admin pages](http://blog.vossers.com/2012/02/04/use-jquery-to-submit-forms-on-remote-sharepoint-admin-pages/)), and a whole lot of 2010 master page code dumps.

Sorry my answer isn't more informative, but neither is the web on this one...

I'm also not really sure what they would do for the "back button functionality," since that's what the encoded `Source` parameter is for in `Request.QueryString`...

Comment: I was looking at this link too and it stated "These must be inside the form at the bottom in order to handle the back button functionality" which didn't really made much of sense to me.

Comment: Yeah, I'm questioning the accuracy of that.

Comment: I'm hoping someone else has a better answer for you because I'm curious too.